# How to use case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use a `CASE` statement instead of an `IF...ELSE` statement but the `CASE` statement give me issues. Please check the stored procedure below. It is complaining about a syntax error next to `UPDATE`.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateRFQStatusDashboardCountForAllUsers]
(
    @UserID [nvarchar](128)='6aab7553-72ef-46d8-b831-5c8d5e269cb3',
    @ColumnName  [nvarchar](50)='Close'
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
  CASE @ColumnName
      WHEN 'New' THEN
       UPDATE [dbo].[RFQStatusDashboardCountForAllUsers]
       SET New = New + 1
       WHERE [UserID] = @UserID
      
      WHEN 'Close' THEN
        UPDATE [dbo].[RFQStatusDashboardCountForAllUsers]
       SET [Open] = [Open] - 1, Closed = Closed + 1
       WHERE [UserID] = @UserID;
      
  END CASE

END
```

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** that returns a *scalar value*, it is *not* a logical flow operator (such as a `switch` statement in C#). It doesn't work like the above. Use `IF...ELSE` logical flow operators.

Comment: Also, as a side note, your parameter `@UserID` looks like it will contain a `uniqueidentifier`, so why do you define it as an `nvarchar(128)`?

Comment: The system am busy maintaining the uniqueidentifier was made a nvarchar(128)